# MQSeries Type of remote channel not suitable

Tags: ibm-mq

Following a slightly modified example I have :

```
public class  MqTestClient {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    MQQueueConnectionFactory factory =
      new MQQueueConnectionFactory(); 
    factory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    factory.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    factory.setPort(1414);
    factory.setQueueManager("QMA");
    factory.setChannel("FROM_CHANNEL");

    MQQueue queue = new MQQueue("QUEUE_FROM"); 

    // connection pooling
    MQEnvironment.addConnectionPoolToken();

    System.out.println("Sending...");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {            
      MQQueueConnection  con = (MQQueueConnection)
        factory.createConnection();
```

With MQ Explorer I've set up a Receiver Channel FROM_CHANNEL and a local queue QUEUE_FROM. This is all run on one Ubuntu machine. I get "Type of remote channel not suitable for action requested". From my searches it looks like this just refers to a sender not sending to a receiver channel which in this case is not the case.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: null
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:585)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:426)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6902)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6277)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6233)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:120)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:203)
    at MqTestClient.main(MqTestClient.java:33)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: JMSCMQ0001, 2, MQCC_FAILED, 2539, MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2539;AMQ9204: Connection to host '127.0.0.1(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2539;AMQ9547: Type of remote channel not suitable for action requested. [3=FROM_CHANNEL]],3=127.0.0.1(1414),5=RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2053)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1226)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:346)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2539;AMQ9547: Type of remote channel not suitable for action requested. [3=FROM_CHANNEL]
```

Comment: In addition to @Shashi's advice, you might want to look at the parameter supplied to `.setHostName`.  I've never seen an IP address specified in text here, just the name of the host (e.g. `"MY_COMPUTER"`).

Comment: the ip seems to work ok since it was earlier giving errors related to specific queues on that localhost. I changed it to the actual hostname anyways. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For client applications to connect to queue manager, a Server connection(SVRCONN) type channel needs to be created. A Receiver (and a Sender) type channel is used for communicating between two queue managers.

Hence please create a Server connection type channel in MQExplorer and specify the name in your client application.